# Delete or Close one's own question, if it appears to be a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, self-delete, self-close

What will be more preferable to delete or vote to close your own question, as you have got a comment this question may be a possible duplicate of any 'given question'?

Comment: deleting streamlines the process, vote to close requires more people

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**If you feel your phrasing of the question is completely unlike the duplicate**, and thus might help future searchers find the same information using different words -- I would move to close as duplicate.

Otherwise, self-deletion is easier and more efficient.

Comment: It's a pity that the question own can't close thier quesion as a duplicate without needing 3 other people to vote.

Comment: I'd like to add - if the question has useful answers / comments beyond those that appear in the duplicate, closing should be preferred above deletion.

Comment: @IanRingrose, are you sure? There is a button "It solved my problem" when somebody proposes a duplicate - in that case question is closed immediately.