# Can my duplicate close vote be binding when I cast it on my own question

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions, self-close

Today I closed a question I asked on MSO, because it was a duplicate.
I voted to close, and was then served with this nice pop-up:
[image]

That asks if it answers my question.

Ofcourse it does, it was me that suggested it.
Can we prevent this behaviour by making [Community♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) automagically cast the final and binding close vote when (at least):

- There are no current close votes on the question
- The close vote is a duplicate vote
- The close vote is from OP

These criteria are up for debate of course.

Comment: Another chance to test it, does this ... https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261430/282094

Comment: @Rob, seeing that that is a 2015 question and mechanics on close voting have changed, at least visually, since then I wont test it here ;)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Voting to close my own question confusingly acts as if I'm not me](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/340297/282094), as [confirmed by Yaakov](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340297/voting-to-close-my-own-question-confusingly-acts-as-if-im-not-me#comment1137263_340305) 5 months ago, ***or*** does it question whether you should instead delete it: [Delete or Close one's own question, if it appears to be a duplicate?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/97399/282094) - IE: [tag:status-bydesign]

Comment: @Rob that first is definetly related, but this is a FR, not a bug.

Comment: Luuklag, the only difference is that Adam *claims* [it's a **bug** because he doesn't understand it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340297/voting-to-close-my-own-question-confusingly-acts-as-if-im-not-me#comment1137277_340305), he says so more than once. While your question is a Feature Request ***because*** 'you *do* understand it' - but it's by-design that it asks "Do we need/want another duplicate (signpost) ***or*** is your question so extremely similar to the proposed duplicate that your question **should simply be deleted** and not marked as a dupe?". UI needs clairity, so bug.